# Cannot instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I´m trying to use a `SearchView` for my Application. First i added `appcompat` to my project:

```
 compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1+"
```

secound i add this code to my menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

but when i start the `activity` i get this:

> 03-07 17:25:39.110  16861-16861/de.treevo.app W/MenuInflater﹕ Cannot
>   instantiate class: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
>       java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:471)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:430)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
>               at de.treevo.app.search.onCreateOptionsMenu(search.java:260)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class 
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:262)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:471)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:430)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
>               at de.treevo.app.search.onCreateOptionsMenu(search.java:260)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:262)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:471)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:430)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
>               at de.treevo.app.search.onCreateOptionsMenu(search.java:260)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path):
>   TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f010030 a=-1}
>               at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2068)
>               at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:129)
>               at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:119)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:262)
>               at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.(SearchView.java:254)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.newInstance(MenuInflater.java:471)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(MenuInflater.java:430)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(MenuInflater.java:451)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:188)
>               at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:110)
>               at de.treevo.app.search.onCreateOptionsMenu(search.java:260)
>               at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2538)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:489)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:853)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:273)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
>               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
>               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

and when i push the search icon nothing happen :(

Edit1:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.offline, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    //setupSearchView(searchItem);

   // menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add a custom prefixe on your layout like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

      <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

See [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView), in the example, you must to add a custom prefixe (as "app" in the code above).

---

Also, instead of:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

Try this:

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
// with MenuItemCompat instead of your MenuItem
mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: nothing happens. it is as has everything with "app" no effect

Comment: It's not everything with "app", just the xmlns (*res-auto*), showAsAction and actionViewClass attributes. Can you edit your question with the code in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: it works thanks :) Just changed MenuItem to MenuItemCompat and Activity to ActionBarActivity

Comment: I have done the same but problem still exist for me.. help me

Answer (score 42):

In my case it works on development mode however crashes on release mode (export signed apk). To fix that please adding this line to `proguard-rules.txt`

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```