# Making a searchview in form through fragment in form

Tags: php, android, mysql, xml, android-fragments

I have a fragment i want to make a Searchview in form that select "mysql" record through "php". I have write some code but these codes creating some syntax error . please help me to do this job. I am Appreciating Your Performance ...

---

**Home.java**

```
 package com.example.synergy.pharmakart.Fragment;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.MatrixCursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.synergy.pharmakart.R;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home extends Fragment {

    // CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds
    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter myAdapter;

    public SearchView searchView;
    SearchView searchItem;
    private String[] strArrData = {"No Suggestions"};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActivity().setTitle("Pharmakart");
        final String[] from = new String[] {"fishName"};
        final int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        myAdapter =  new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null, from, to, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

        // Fetch data from mysql table using AsyncTask
         new AsyncFetch().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        searchItem = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchItem.setIconified(false);
            }
        });
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if (searchItem != null) {
            searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconified(false);
            searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter);
            // Getting selected (clicked) item suggestion
            searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

                    // Add clicked text to search box
                    android.widget.CursorAdapter ca = searchView.getSuggestionsAdapter();
                    Cursor cursor = ca.getCursor();
                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                    searchView.setQuery(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fishName")), false);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

                    // Filter data
                    final MatrixCursor mc = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{BaseColumns._ID, "fishName"});
                    for (int i = 0; i < strArrData.length; i++) {
                        if (strArrData[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(s.toLowerCase()))
                            mc.addRow(new Object[]{i, strArrData[i]});
                    }
                    myAdapter.changeCursor(mc);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            if (searchView != null) {
                searchView.clearFocus();
            }

            // User entered text and pressed search button. Perform task ex: fetching data from database and display

        }
    }

    private class AsyncFetch extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides or your JSON file address
                url = new URL("http://synergywebdesigners.com/synergywebdesigners.com/ashish/PHP/fetch-all-fish.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {

                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                // setDoOutput to true as we receive data
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return (result.toString());

                } else {
                    return("Connection error");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
            pdLoading.dismiss();


            if(result.equals("no rows")) {

                // Do some action if no data from database

            }else{

                try {

                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    // Extract data from json and store into ArrayList
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        dataList.add(json_data.getString("fish_name"));
                    }

                    strArrData = dataList.toArray(new String[dataList.size()]);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // You to understand what actually error is and handle it appropriately
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

---

**fragment_home.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.synergy.pharmakart.Fragment.Home">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100sp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/image" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <SearchView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:id="@+id/search"
                    android:label="@string/search_hint"
                    android:showAsAction="always"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextstyle"
                    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="@string/advertisment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/discount"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <TextView
                    android:text="or"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:gravity="center"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <Button
                        android:text="Quick Order"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/button"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="@string/prescription"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_left"
                        android:textSize="10sp"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Get upto"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textView6"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="20% off"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textView7"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorOffer"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="On medicine*"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textView8"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorOffer"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:text="(Delivery charges Rs. 25/-)"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textView9"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_left"
                            android:gravity="center"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:text="Service available in Delhi."
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/text10"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorOffer"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

---

Please Help me do this . I am so confused How can I do this .

Comment: searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

Comment: searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(myAdapter); these tow lines creating a error

Comment: myAdapter is creating a error. Error is:  SearchView cannot be applied
to
(android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter)